# RegExp ignore special and repeated characters (username test)

Tags: regex

All,
I am trying to construct a regular expression (I will use to test valid usernames):

```
^[(0-9)|(_|\.)]|^[0-9]+$|[^a-zA-z0-9_.]{3,}|(_\.|\._)|\.{2,}|_{2,}
```

and testing it against this string:

```
1123@sssssasdf sslkdf*.sf...____.__sfsfdddddsss
```

What this regular expression should test is:

1. string should not begin with numbers, underscore or dot
2. string should be alphanumeric
3. should not contain characters repeated thrice or more --this fails
4. should not contain underscore and dot together
5. should not contain dot and underscore together
6. should not contain repeated dots should not contain repeated underscores

It looks like all of the cases are matched but 3rd. It doesn't catch repeated characters that are repeated thrice or more.

My questions are:

1. How can I fix this regular expression so it can catch repeated characters?
2. How can I optimize this regular expression?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
As requested the valid string are:

1. john
2. john.snow
3. john.snow123
4. john1.snow1
5. john_snow
6. john_snow123
7. john1_snow1

The invalid strings are:

1. 123
2. 1john.snow
3. .john_snow
4. john__snow
5. john..snow
6. jjjohn.snow
7. _john_snow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?![0-9_.])(?!.*([._])\1)(?!.*(?:_\.|\._))(?!.*(.)\2{2,})[\w.]+$
```

You can add a `negative lookahead` for each of the condition.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rO0yD8/6

Answer (score 1):

And can be done this way too -

`(?i)^(?=[a-z])(?!.*?(?:\._|_\.|\.{2}|_{2}|([a-z\d])\1{2}))[a-z\d._]+$`

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?i)                # Case insensitive
 ^                   # BOS
 (?= [a-z] )         # First char alpha
 (?!                 # Not these
      .*? 
      (?:
           \._                 # dot, underscore
        |  _\.                 # underscore, dot
        |  \.{2}               # 2 or more dots
        |  _{2}                # 3 or more underscore
        |  ( [a-z\d] )         # (1), 3 or more repeated alpha-num's
           \1{2} 
      )
 )
 [a-z\d._]+          # Get valid char's: alpha-num, dot and underscore
 $                   # EOS
```